# Vectorplot shows empty result

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I've tried to draw a vector plot with piecewise functions, but it shows empty result.
When I don't use piecewise functions, Vectorplot works well..
I can't figure out what the problem is.
I would really appreciate if someone helps me.
The whole code is below.

```
A = 5;
b = 0.6;
theta = 0.7;
lambda = 1;
rho = 0.9;
eta = 0.3;
B = 2;
alpha = 1;
i = 0.1;
uppergamma = 1.4;
lowergamma = 0.4;
Delta = 1;
delta = 1;

u[q_] = A q^b;
up[q_] = A b q^(b-1);

F[x_] = 
Piecewise[{
{1, x > uppergamma},
{0, x < lowergamma},
{(x-lowergamma)/(uppergamma-lowergamma), lowergamma <= x <= uppergamma}
}];

integrateF[x_] = 
Piecewise[{
{0, x < lowergamma},
{x-uppergamma + 0.5, x > uppergamma},
{0.5*(x-lowergamma)^2, lowergamma <= x <= uppergamma}
}];

yinner[n_, i_] = y /. FindRoot[theta*(up[y]-1)/((1-theta)*up[y]+theta) == i/(alpha*n), {y, 0.001}];
y[n_,i_] = If[Im[yinner[n,i]]==0, yinner[n,i], 0];

niso[gamma_] = Max[0, lambda*F[gamma]/(delta+lambda*F[gamma])];
gammaiso[n_] = gamma /. 
FindRoot[(rho+delta)*gamma + lambda*integrateF[gamma] 
== alpha*(1-theta)*(u[y[n,i]]-y[n,i]), {gamma, 0.001}]

Show[{


ParametricPlot[{n, gammaiso[n]}, {n, 0, 1},  PlotRange -> {{0,1}, {0,uppergamma}},
PlotStyle -> {Blue}, AxesLabel -> {n, gamma},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, PlotLegends -> {Style["gamma_R dot = 0", 12]}],


ParametricPlot[{niso[gamma], gamma}, {gamma, 0, uppergamma}, PlotRange -> {{0,1}, {0,uppergamma}},
PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {n, gamma},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, PlotLegends -> {Style["ndot=0", 12]}], 


VectorPlot[{(1-n)*lambda*F[gamma]-delta*n,
(rho+delta)*gamma + lambda*integrateF[gamma]  - alpha *(1-theta)*(u[y[n,i]]-y[n,i])},
{n, 0, 1}, {gamma, 0, uppergamma}]

}]
```

[image]

Comment: I just replaced all your `=` with `:=` and it worked. Why are you defining functions with `=` and not `:=`?     always use `:=` for functions unless you have specific reason not to. V 13.1 screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWAfY.png)

Comment: Just to add to Nasser’s useful comment:  it’s ok—preferred even—to use = on your constants (as in b=6). As Nasser says, use :=  in function defs (e.g., f[x_]:=x).  There are exceptions that have to do with efficiency, but for most users := is the way to go for function definitions.  Trying to understand why would be a rewarding task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact values for constants.

```
A = 5;
b = 3/5;
theta = 7/10;
lambda = 1;
rho = 9/10;
eta = 3/10;
B = 2;
alpha = 1;
i = 1/10;
uppergamma = 7/5;
lowergamma = 2/5;
Delta = 1;
delta = 1;

u[q_] = A q^b;
up[q_] = A b q^(b - 1);

F[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, x > uppergamma}, {0, 
     x < lowergamma}, {(x - lowergamma)/(uppergamma - lowergamma), 
     lowergamma <= x <= uppergamma}}];

integrateF[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < lowergamma}, {x - uppergamma + 1/2, 
      x > uppergamma}, {1/2*(x - lowergamma)^2, 
      lowergamma <= x <= uppergamma}}] // Simplify;
```

`yinner` can be solved exactly

```
yinner[n_, iv_] = 
 SolveValues[theta*(up[y] - 1)/((1 - theta)*up[y] + theta) == iv/(alpha*n), y,
     Reals][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

The condition on `yinner` indicates when it is real

```
y[n_, iv_] = Piecewise[{List @@ yinner[n, iv]}]
```

[image]

```
niso[gamma_] = 
  Max[0, lambda*F[gamma]/(delta + lambda*F[gamma])] // PiecewiseExpand // 
   FullSimplify;
```

Functions such as `FindRoot` that use numeric techniques should restrict their arguments to numeric values and use `SetDelayed`.

```
gammaiso[n_?NumericQ] := 
 gamma /. FindRoot[(rho + delta)*gamma + lambda*integrateF[gamma] == 
    alpha*(1 - theta)*(u[y[n, i]] - y[n, i]), {gamma, 1/1000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

Plotting,

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[{n, gammaiso[n]}, {n, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, uppergamma}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   AxesLabel -> {n, gamma}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
   PlotLegends -> {Style["gamma_R dot = 0", 12]}], 
  ParametricPlot[{niso[gamma], gamma}, {gamma, 0, uppergamma}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, uppergamma}}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   AxesLabel -> {n, gamma}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
   PlotLegends -> {Style["ndot=0", 12]}], 
  VectorPlot[{(1 - n)*lambda*F[gamma] - delta*n, (rho + delta)*gamma + 
        lambda*integrateF[gamma] - alpha*(1 - theta)*(u[y[n, i]] - y[n, i])} //
       PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify // Evaluate, {n, 0, 1}, {gamma, 0, 
    uppergamma}]}]
```

[image]